# How can I use TiKZ to design comments in the margin of an environment which allows a pagebreak?

Tags: tikz-pgf, environments

To distinguish different classes of environments, I use the environment `shaded` from the package `framed`.

Then, I would like to design a corresponding environment using TiKZ where a line with a description should appear instead of a backgorund color. Therefore, I used the command `\newenviron` from the package `newenviron`. My attempt (see code below) is acceptable if the entry in the environment does not require a pagebreak, although it is narrower than the former one.

Thus, I have two questions

1. How can I define an environment where I can design (using TiKZ; this is important for an other reason) a comment in the margin such that it also admits pagebreaks? (seeking for a correction/extension of my environment `lbox`)
2. How can I guarantee that the width is the same as in the framed-version? (I already implemented that I can switch between these two modes with a control command to safe printer's ink)

Thanks!

Here is a relavant example code, where the problems become obvious:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{newenviron} 

\newenviron{lbox}[1]
  {\par \hspace*{-1.05cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[inner xsep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,inner ysep=2mm] (box)
    {\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\lboxbody}};
\draw[black,line width=0.5pt]
      ( $ (box.north west) + (-0.4cm,0) $ )
      --node[pos=0,rotate=90,above,anchor=south east]
      {\scriptsize{\textsc{#1}}} ( $ (box.south west) + (-0.4cm,0) $ ) ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
}{}

\usepackage{framed,color}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{red!30}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{shaded}
\blindtext
\end{shaded}

\begin{lbox}{Comment}
\blindtext
\end{lbox}

\begin{shaded}
\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext
\end{shaded}

\begin{lbox}{Comment}
\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext
\end{lbox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Check the tcolorbox package.

Answer (score 1):

`tcolorbox` is useful for framed breakable boxes. Next code shows two examples,
the first one `tshaded` adds some colorful background to a paragraph while `lbox` draws a line with an optional text. If this text ("comment") should only appear on first part of a breakable box, change `overlay` for `overlay first` (from page 63 in documentation).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{framed,xcolor}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{red!30}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{tshaded}[1][]{breakable, oversize, notitle, enhanced, 
    colback=shadecolor, boxrule=0pt, sharp corners, #1}

\newtcolorbox{lbox}[1]{breakable, blanker, oversize, notitle, colback=white,
     boxrule=0pt, left=4mm, right=4mm,
    overlay={\draw[black, line width=.5pt] (frame.south west) -- (frame.north west)
    node[anchor=south east, rotate=90, font=\scriptsize\scshape] {#1};}}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{tshaded}
\blindtext
\end{tshaded}

\begin{lbox}{Comment}
\blindtext
\end{lbox}

\begin{tshaded}[colback=green!20]
\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext
\end{tshaded}

\begin{lbox}{Another comment}
\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext
\end{lbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]